# Bounty not doing anything?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, bounties

I spent 500 reputation in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455931/extracting-text-from-a-contenteditable-div) and it accomplished exactly... nothing, it doesn't even show up on the featured tab, nor on any of it's pages (at least to the date), when you opt to browse "all of them"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just put a bounty on that question.

It does show up on the Featured tab, it is currently on the last page. As the bounty gets closer to its expiration date it will be ranked higher in the feature tab. As it is now, you still have 7 days left. Give it time.

Comment: Exactly - the Featured tab sorts bounty questions by their Bounty Close date, ascending; the sooner they end, the higher on the tab they appear.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the OP showed up and posted an answer pretty quickly. Seems to have done it's job, unless you're looking for something other than the posted answer.